# How to blend between LUT textures in Unity's color correction script?

Tags: image-processing, unity-game-engine, shader

According to this document:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/ColorGrading.html

It seems you can blend multiple LUT textures in Unreal Engine.

Is there any similar way to achieve this in Unity?

For example, I need to switch LUT effect off in some situation. How to blend between LUT textures in Unity's color correction script?

Answer (score 0):

in Unity 2017.1.x and later, you can use the new Post Processing Stack,
it supports effect-volumes and lerping between them (basically trigger areas to  decide which post effect is applied)

post processing stack v2
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/tree/v2